# ExtJS - dirty check on form works only the first time

Tags: extjs

I am doing a dirty check before submitting a Edit details form. This works the first time after the form is loaded, but if I submit the form once, the dirty check ceases to work on subsequent calls.

```
if(editForm.getForm().isDirty()) {
    editForm.getForm().submit( {
        url:'app/update',
        waitMsg:'Saving data',
        success:function(form,action) {
              Ext.Msg.alert("Success", "Successfully updated");
        },
        failure: function(form,action) {
              Ext.Msg.alert("Failure", "Failed to update");
        }
    });
} else {
    Ext.Msg.alert("Message", "Nothing has been changed since you last saved.");
}
```

Comment: I don't think there will be any quicker way to implement this. `isDirty` is a method that loop through all the fields and look for dirty fields, so it will always return `true` if you have modified any bit that differs from the data that was loaded at the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because your form is comparing the field values with initial field values.

You can use the `reset()` method to reset the form after submit. If you need to provide users to continue edit on the same form, you can reload the form with latest data using `loadRecord()` method. Or you will have to make use of the `trackResetOnLoad` property. Set this property to true.

Comment: I tried editForm.getForm().reset();editForm.getForm().loadRecord(action.result.data); in the success callback, but it still did not work.

Comment: my bad. It should have been - 'editForm.getForm().loadRecord(action.result);'

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me. I added this after a successful form submit.

```
form.getForm().getFields().each(function(field){
   field.resetOriginalValue( );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the Ext.form.Panel property trackResetOnLoad ? Try setting it to true by stating editForm.trackResetOnLoad = true; this might help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I thought I'd share another solution.

The isDirty() method checks against the original values. Upon saving the values (in your success call back function) you could have this code which sets the originalValues to your new successfully saved values:

```
var fields = editForm.getForm.getFields().items;
Ext.each(fields, function(field){
    field.originalValue = field.getValue();
});
```